# How to use Apache to proxy from subfolder to other server

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy, rewrite

Given the following url:

domain.com/wiki/

I'd like apache to redirect all requests below that (so domain.com/wiki/*) to otherdomain.com:8080/.  But the trick is I want the user to always see domain.com/wiki/.  And the webapp on otherdomain thinks it's running at the root level, so has internal links to css and images and such that are like /css/style.css.  Those urls need to be rewritten to /wiki/css/style.css.

The following config gets mostly there but is missing the /css & /images rewrite solution:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /wiki/ http://otherdomain.com:8080/
ProxyPassReverse /wiki/ http://otherdomain.com:8080/
```

Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: check this answer, note the ending slash is NOT mandatory 
 http://serverfault.com/questions/429122/apache-virtualhost-proxy-with-a-subdirectory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use something like ProxyHTMLURLMap.
If I remember it correctly it would work like this:

`ProxyHTMLURLMap     http://domain.com/wiki/css       http://otherdomain.com:8080/css    [R]`

Comment: This looks right, and here's a nice example of how to do what I'm looking for: http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies