# Apache reverse proxy not working and generates a 404 error

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, jetty

I have an installation of Shiboleth that runs on Jetty 9. Through Apache I have a reverse proxy to the 8080 port of Jetty which serves the Shiboleth instance.

When I curl http://localhost:8080/idp/shibboleth in the console, the instance responce is generated correctly.

However when I do the same on my browser https://idp.example.com/idp/shibboleth I get a 404 error.

This is some indication that the reverse proxy is not working correctly?

This is my apache conf

```
SSLUseStapling on
SSLStaplingResponderTimeout 5
SSLStaplingReturnResponderErrors off
SSLStaplingCache shmcb:/var/run/ocsp(128000)

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName "idp.spectrum.com.cy"
Redirect permanent "/" "https://idp.spectrum.com.cy/"
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
 ServerName idp.spectrum.com.cy:443
 ServerAdmin pieros.tzamas@spectrum.com.cy
 # Debian
 CustomLog /var/log/apache2/idp.spectrum.com.cy.log combined
 ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/idp.spectrum.com.cy.org-error.log
 # Centos
 #CustomLog /var/log/httpd/idp.example.org.log combined
 #ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/idp.example.org-error.log
 
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/idp.spectrum.com.cy
 
 SSLEngine On
 SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
 SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4"

 SSLHonorCipherOrder on
 
 # Disallow embedding your IdP's login page within an iframe and
 # Enable HTTP Strict Transport Security with a 2 year duration
 <IfModule headers_module>
    Header set X-Frame-Options DENY
    Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000 ; includeSubDomains ; preload"
 </IfModule>
 
 # Debian
 SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/idp.spectrum.com.cy.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/idp.spectrum.com.cy.key

 # ACME-CA or GEANT_OV_RSA_CA_4 (For users who use GARR TCS/Sectigo RSA Organization Validation Secure Server CA)
 #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ACME-CA.pem
 #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/GEANT_OV_RSA_CA_4.pem


 # Centos
 #SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/idp.example.org.crt
 #SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/idp.example.org.key

 # ACME-CA or GEANT_OV_RSA_CA_4 (For users who use GARR TCS/Sectigo RSA Organization Validation Secure Server CA)
 #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ACME-CA.pem
 #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/GEANT_OV_RSA_CA_4.pem

 <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    ProxyPass /idp http://localhost:8080/idp/ retry=5
    ProxyPassReverse /idp http://localhost:8080/idp/ retry=5

    <Location /idp>
       Require all granted
    </Location>
 </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
  ProxyPass /idp  http://localhost:8080/idp/ retry=5
  ProxyPassReverse /idp http://localhost:8080/idp/ retry=5
  <Location /idp>
   Require all granted
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have simplified my conf file in order to remove https. The configuration below works fine but with http only. I will investigate why the https configuration generates 404 error.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName idp.spectrum.com.cy

 <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /idp/ http://localhost:8080/idp/ retry=5
    ProxyPassReverse /idp/ http://localhost:8080/idp/ retry=5

    <Location /idp>
       Require all granted
    </Location>
 </IfModule>
```

```
# This virtualhost is only here to handle administrative commands 
for Shibboleth, executed from localhost
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
  ProxyPass /idp  http://localhost:8080/idp/ retry=5
  ProxyPassReverse /idp http://localhost:8080/idp/ retry=5
  <Location /idp>
    Require all granted
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Im unsure, but my stomach thinks, that there is no defination for /idp to anywhere. you can take a look on https://serverfault.com/questions/429122/apache-virtualhost-proxy-with-a-subdirectory for a hint to solve your issue

Comment: @djdomi when I curl to http//localhost:8080/idp I still get an answer from the shibboleth instance. So I guess this is not the case...?

Comment: Yes `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>` has an entry for it, but not `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` or lets explain in other words: each VirtualHost is like a Standalone apache installation

Comment: If we are on the same page. There are three Virtual Hosts on the above. One is for port 80 that redirects to https, one for https on port 443 (the one I think you say is missing) and one for the localhost on port 80.

Comment: Is mod_proxy enabled?

Comment: You might want to remove all those IfModule directives, they have their uses but most often they hide problems instead of preventing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's supposed to be

```
ProxyPass /idp/ http://localhost:8080/idp/
```

Note the trailing slash in the `ProxyPass` command's first argument. Always align the trailing slashes in both arguments.

My `VirtualHost` declarations are pretty basic and only contain the bare minimum to work:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ServerName idp.example.com
    ServerAlias idp
    ErrorLog  logs/error_log
    CustomLog logs/access_log    
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/idp.example.com.key
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/idp.example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/chain.crt

    ServerName idp.example.com
    ServerAlias idp
    ErrorLog  logs/ssl-error_log
    CustomLog logs/ssl-access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here's my IDP's `/etc/httpd/conf.d/idp.conf`:

```
ProxyPass /idp/ http://localhost:8080/idp/ retry=5
ProxyPassReverse /idp/ http://localhost:8080/idp/

<Proxy http://localhost:8080>
       Require all granted
       RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
       RequestHeader set X-Proxied-Https on
       RequestHeader set Proxy-ssl-id %{SSL_SESSION_ID}s
</Proxy>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. The trailing slash was missing. That simple. I had some more issues but without the trailing slash I would not resolve them.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the port from the `ServerName` directive. I.e.,

```
ServerName idp.spectrum.com.cy
```

Per https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername the port is optional and allowed, but the following mention in the documentation sounds like it may be the reason why that `VirtualHost` configuration is not picking up (browsers do not sent the port number in the `Host:` header).

> If you are using [name-based virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html), the `ServerName` inside a
> [`<VirtualHost>`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost) section specifies what hostname must appear in the
> request's `Host:` header to match this virtual host.

Comment: I have tried the ServerName with and without the port wihtout any difference. I have ommited the port based on the docs your provided. Thanks for the input.